# asp.net login security can't run login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, authorization

I am following along the following tutorial to create security for my classic asp.net website, and I am a novice at security.

http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/12/forms-authentication-using-user-names.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoRWKBbc6QI&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXQS_p1i-HLIftB9Y7Vnxlo&index=90

I can't even run the login page because of the following lines in webconfig:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Well, I think this is not supposed to apply to the login page, because it is defined with LoginUrl characteristic, like this:

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Disclaimer.aspx" protection="All">
```

So, the startup page of my app is defined as Login.aspx, and when the app rus in Visual Studio ide, it complains that "Access is denied".

My login page need not have any code on it at this point.  Even if I delete all the code, I won't be able to run the startup page itself, because access is denied, even though it is a startup login page.

My webconig is like this (most of the code is generated, only I added the code in 'XXXXXXXX')

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>


    <!--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Disclaimer.aspx" protection="All">

        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="Venkat" password="Venkat"/>
          <user name="Pragim" password="Pragim"/>       
        </credentials>


      </forms>
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <!--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-->



    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
      </dependentAssembly>      
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I wonder if  the following code is only supposed to be in webconfig of all other pages accessed by site:  <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>     That's now how the tutorial reads, though....

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing access to your login page.

```
<location path="~/folderpath/Login.aspx"> 
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```